# Configure git to throw error on using certain characters in branch name

Tags: git, git-branch, git-config

I recently figured that my organization's build process fails to succeed if your branch contains **/** in the branch name because the build process generates a file with filename `<blah>_<branch_name>.type` in folder say RootFolder.

eg. Branch name: dev/someDev/someBranch

```
   FileName: `<blah>_dev/someDev/someBranch.type`
```

Since branch name contains **/**, the file actually gets created at `RootFolder\<blah>_dev\someDev\` with the file name being `someBranch.type`.
Now the process expecting the file in RootFolder doesn't find the file which causes the build process to fail.

So, is there a way I can configure git to throw an error in case the branch name contains certain illegal characters?

NOTE: At this is point I cannot change the build process. Also, I know there are several other ways to name a branch say: `dev-someDev-someBranch` by which we can avoid hitting this build failure but I am curious to see if I can configure git in the above manner.

Comment: Backslash is not a legal character in a branch name (nor any reference). See rule #10 of https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html

Comment: @torek Sorry for the confusion. I meant forward-slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you did not tell us *where* you'd like the branch names to be checked against your policy—on the developers' machines or in the repository they push to or in the repository your build server fetches into (if eny) or somewhere else completely.

I think the simplest to configure point for such check is the repository the devs push their work to.

To implement such policy enforcement you'll need to write and enable a so-called *hook* in that repository; specifically, a `pre-receive` hook.

Hooks are scripts (or any other kind of executable programs) which Git calls when carrying out specific actions on a repository.  See `git help hooks` to read an overview.  Each hook must follow a certain convention to work with Git.  Typically hooks read data supplied by Git from their standard input stream, write nothing to their standard output stream and signalize success (or "OK to continue") by exiting with the status code 0 and failure (or "not OK continue") by exiting with a non-zero exit code; in the latter case they may write an error message to their standard error stream.

The hook of interest, `pre-receive` rolls like this:

> `pre-receive`
>   This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository, which
>   happens when a git push is done on a local repository.
>   Just before starting to update refs on the remote repository,
>   the `pre-receive` hook is invoked. Its exit status determines the success or failure of the update.
>
> This hook executes once for the receive operation.
>   It takes no arguments, but for each ref to be updated it receives on standard input a line of the format:
>
> ```
> <old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
> ```
>
> where `<old-value>` is the old object name stored in the ref,
>   `<new-value>` is the new object name to be stored in the ref
>   and `<ref-name>` is the full name of the ref.
>   When creating a new ref, `<old-value>` is 40 0.
>
> If the hook exits with non-zero status, none of the refs will be updated.
>   If the hook exits with zero, updating of individual refs can still be
>   prevented by the update hook.
>
> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to
>   `git send-pack` on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.

So, you'd need to write a hook program which reads the data from its standard input stream, interprets it as a set of `LF`-separated lines,
break each into three fields separated by two `SP` (space) characters
and check the third field—which will be a branch name—has no
invalid characters as per your policy.

If your hook detects poilcy violation it should write a message to its standard error stream and exit with a non-zero exit code.
This will make Git not update the repository with the data a developer
attempted to push into it.

Comment: The third field will be a *reference* name. This a branch name if and only if it begins with `refs/heads/`. If it begins with `refs/tags/` it is a tag name; if it starts with `refs/notes/` it is from `git notes`. That said, this is generally the right answer and I've upvoted it :-) although backslash is forbidden in all references anyway, so the original question has a bigger technical issue with it!

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer. This is exactly the level of pertinence and detail I was looking for.